# Having some kind of grit

Tags: meaning, expressions, slang

What does the expression, "You have got some kind of grit," mean?

Is it sarcastic, like being a bit crazy?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

"Grit" is defined as:

> courage and resolve; strength of character

Saying that you have "some kind of" something is another way to say that you have a "variation of" or "form of" that thing. "Some kind of grit" means that you have a form of grit. The connotation of the phrase implies that you have an exceptional or uncommon grit. Completely reworded:

> You have an unusual amount of courage.

There is a significant difference between "some kind of" and "a bit" in the sense that "a bit" is a sarcastic reference to the quantity of something. "A bit crazy" means "a lot crazy"; "some kind of" carries no such connotation. Its literal meaning is very close to its practical meaning.

Comment: Thanks. Would you say that it would mean quite the same as *having the nerve to do something*, or maybe *being perseverant* ?

Comment: Yes. "Having the nerve" usually implies that the action is rude or unexpected but "grit" can cover the same ground. Both imply "courage".

Answer (score 2):

The word *grit* in this sense is defined as

> grit: firmness of mind or spirit : unyielding courage in the face of hardship or danger

So saying that some has

> some kind of grit

means that they are strong and usually courageous. Or willing to face danger.

So, "a bit crazy" could make sense here.

Answer (score 0):

I take it to be similar to the phrase "You have got a lot of nerve."